# Is there way to ignore 302 Moved Temporarily redirection or find what it is caused by?

Tags: python, redirect, python-3.x, urllib

I am Writing some parsing script and need to access to many web pages like this [one](http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm?bay=search.summary&orgid=13546).

Whenever I try to get this page with `urlopen` and then `read()`, I get redirected to this [page](http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm?bay=search.advanced).

When I launch the same links from google chrome redirect happens but really rarely, most of times when I try to launch url not by clicking it from site menus.

Is there way to dodge that redirect or simulate jump to url from web-site menus with python3?

Example code:

```
def getItemsFromPage(url):
    with urlopen(url) as page:
        html_doc = str(page.read())
    return re.findall('(http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm\?bay=search\.summary&amp;orgid=[\d]+)', html_doc)

url = 'http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm?bay=search.alpha&ltr=1'
items_urls = getItemsFromPage(url)
with urlopen(item_urls[0]) as item_page:
    print(item_page.read().decode('utf-8')) # Here i get search.advanced instead of item page
```

Comment: First try it with http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ requests library,  and check whether HTTP Referer setting in the request helps. Another possibility is that cookies are used somehow to prevent "deep linking". Yet another - user agent. Only traffic analysis with some tools for that could tell the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it's a weird problem with ampersands from raw html data. When you visit the webpage and click on link ampersands (&amp) are read by web navigator as "&" and it work. However, python reads data as it is, that is raw data. So:

```
import urllib.request as net
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import re 

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0",
}

def unescape(items):
    html = HTMLParser()
    unescaped = []
    for i in items:
        unescaped.append(html.unescape(i))

    return unescaped


def getItemsFromPage(url):
    request = net.Request(url, headers=headers)
    response = str(net.urlopen(request).read())
    # --------------------------
    # FIX AMPERSANDS - unescape
    # --------------------------
    links = re.findall('(http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm\?bay=search\.summary&amp;orgid=[\d]+)', response)
    unescaped_links = unescape(links)

    return unescaped_links


url = 'http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm?bay=search.alpha&ltr=1'
item_urls = getItemsFromPage(url)
request = net.Request(item_urls[0], headers=headers)
print(item_urls)
response = net.urlopen(request)

# DEBUG RESPONSE 
print(response.url)
print(80 * '-')

print("<title>Charity Navigator Rating - 10,000 Degrees</title>" in (response.read().decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: Oh, god, i totally forged about decoding those html entities and already considered (and fixed) so many things that 'caused' redirections... That was so simple. Thank you for help!

Comment: @WhereIsMyMind Actually, I think you have a lot of luck. Because in the most times it is need to fake http headers and manage cookies inviacookiejars etc. But on your case it was simple anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not replacing `&amp;` with `&` in the url string. I rewrite your code using urllib3 as below and got the expected webpages.

```
import re
import urllib3

def getItemsFromPage(url):
    # create connection pool object (urllib3-specific)
    localpool = urllib3.PoolManager() 
    with localpool.request('get', url) as page:
        html_doc = page.data.decode('utf-8')
    return re.findall('(http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm\?bay=search\.summary&amp;orgid=[\d]+)', html_doc)

# the master webpage
url_master = 'http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm?bay=search.alpha&ltr=1'
# name and store the downloaded contents for testing purpose.
file_folder = "R:"
file_mainname = "test"

# parse the master webpage
items_urls = getItemsFromPage(url_master)

# create pool
mypool = urllib3.PoolManager()

i=0;
for url in items_urls:
    # file name to be saved
    file_name = file_folder + "\\" + file_mainname + str(i) + ".htm"
    # replace '&amp;' with r'&'
    url_OK = re.sub(r'&amp;', r'&', url)
    # print revised url
    print(url_OK) 
    ### the urllib3-pythonic way of web page retrieval ###
    with mypool.request('get', url_OK) as page, open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(page.data.decode('utf-8'))
    i+=1
```

(verified on python 3.4 eclipse PyDev win7 x64)